# How to display colored emojis in XTerm

Tags: debian, terminal, fonts, xterm, emoji

I want to be able to display colored emojis in XTerm, for example those from Noto Color Emoji of the [`fonts-noto-color-emoji`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/fonts-noto-color-emoji) font package. Like [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1122326/is-there-a-way-to-get-colored-emoji-in-any-terminal-emulator-on-linux), but specifically for XTerm.

Comment: Internet search found this post https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/58706 where XTerm maintainer Thomas Dickey commented "I'll add a workaround in xterm", so I guess, in principle, it *should* be possible to use colored emojis with XTerm. But I cannot work out how.

Comment: Does it have to be XTerm, or can we suggest other terminal emulators?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks for the reply :) I'm looking for a solution specifically for XTerm. I have linked another question which discusses other terminal emulators in my text above. No issues there.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, found a workaround. When starting xterm with a font emojis show up (`font-symbola` might be required):

```
xterm -fa '$FONTNAME'
```

### Examples

`xterm -fa 'Overpass Regular' -fs 11`

[image: xterm with overpass regular]

`xterm -fa 'Dank Mono' -fs 11`

[image: xterm with dank mono]

```
[...] on  develop [!] via ⬢ v14.7.0 
❯ echo " "
```

[image: emoji test]

Comment: This makes colored emojis like  show up for you?

Comment: @finefoot ⬢ and ❯ didn't work before and show up now.   works,  doesn't work,  works. note: they do not look colored, only a "flat white 2d" version is shown.

Edit: I added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Yes okay, but please look at the title of this question: colored emojis are exactly what I'm looking for  So your answer unfortunately doesn't help me

Comment: the package `font-symbola` points out that my answer is not about colored emojis, but about a work around to not have undefined symbols 